# How can I go through an array of odd numbers and add 5 to each instance?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var oddNumbers = [Int]()

for x in 0...100 where x % 2 != 0{
    oddNumbers.append(x)
}



var sums = [Any]()

for i in 0..<oddNumbers.count {
    sums = oddNumbers[i] + 5.0
}
```

I spent about an hour trying different things and can't seem to get it right. I've gotten like 3 different error messages but the one I get for this one is `Cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument of type [Any]`.

Comment: Looks like you want something like this: `var sums = [Int]()` and `sums.append(oddNumbers[i] + 5)`

Comment: Why do you want sum to be of type `[Any]` when it is an `[Int]`? Also you're not appending anything to sums. You're assigning a double value to `sums` which is an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you need to use `append` to add object in array because currently you assigning single value to array also instead of declaring array of `Any` declare `sums` as array of `Double` because you want to add `5.0` in each elements of array `oddNumbers` if you want to just add `5` then declare `sums` as array of `Int` because here no need to declare array of `Any` when you already know its type.

```
var sums = [Double]()
for i in 0..<oddNumbers.count {
    sums.append(Double(oddNumbers[i]) + 5.0)
}
```

But instead of these two `for loops` you can simply use `flatMap` like this to make your desired array.

```
let sums = (0...100).flatMap { $0 % 2 != 0 ? Double($0) + 5.0 : nil  }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Sequential odd numbers in a given range: `stride(...)`

If you want to construct an array of sequential odd numbers, your needn't necessarily *compute* these by using the remainder operator `%`, but could simply use [`stride(from:through:by)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641185-stride), starting at the first odd number (`1`) and striding forward with a fixed stride of `2`:

```
let oddNumbers = Array(stride(from: 1, through: 100, by: 2))
    // [Int]

oddNumbers.forEach { print($0) }
/* 1
   3
   5
   ...
   95
   97
   99 */
```

If you directly want to compute all odd numbers from `0` to `100` and map a type conversion to `Double` as well as an addition of `5.0` to these converted values, then you can apply this `map` operation directly on the `stride(...)`:

```
let sums = stride(from: 1, through: 100, by: 2).map { Double($0) + 5.0 } 
    // [Double]

sums.forEach { print($0) }
/* 6.0
   8.0
   10.0
   ...
   98.0
   100.0
   102.0
   104.0 */
```

Or, better yet, apply the constant value shift (`5`) directly to the `stride(...)` and simply perform a `Double` initialization in the `map`:

```
let sums = stride(from: 1+5, through: 100+5, by: 2).map(Double.init)
    // [Double]

sums.forEach { print($0) }
/* 6.0
   8.0
   10.0
   ...
   98.0
   100.0
   102.0
   104.0 */
```

Answer (score 2):

According to newly released **Swift 5** you can determine this using `flatMap` and [isMultiple(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127688-ismultiple) method

```swift
let sums = (0...100).flatMap { !$0.isMultiple(of: 2) ? Double($0) + 5.0 : nil }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little math, you can use a functional programming approach without any loops.

For example:

```
let n = 100
let oddNumbers = (1...(n+1)/2).map{$0 * 2 - 1}
let sums       = oddNumbers.map{$0 + 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let sums = (0...100).filter { $0 % 2 != 0 }.map { $0 + 5 }
```

Explanation: Create a range 0 to 100, filter out even numbers, use map to transform each element to itself plus 5